# get all UTF8 vowels from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

On our country the vowels are these characters: **a ı o u e ə i ö ü**. I want to find all vowels from a given string. My code is:

```
$string = "Firuzə";
preg_match_all('/[aıoueəiöü]/i',$string,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

It returns me this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => i
    [1] => u
    [2] => �
    [3] => �
)
```

But I want to return this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => i
    [1] => u
    [2] => ə
)
```

Comment: add your answer. i will mark as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `u` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for unicode regex:

```
/[aıoueəiöü]/iu
```

(the pattern has to be utf-8 too)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[a\x{131}oue\x{259}i\xF6\xFC]
```

Comment: PHP doesn't support Unicode escapes of the form `\uhhhh`, either in string literals or in regexes.  But you can use `\x{hhhh}` notation in regexes: `[a\x{0131}oue\x{0259}i\x{00F6}\x{00FC}]`